# How to convert one partial function to another?

Tags: scala, partialfunction

Suppose I've got partial function `parf`

```
val parf: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case 0 => "!!!" }
```

Now I've got also `case class A(x: Int)` and I need a function to transform `PartialFunction[Int, String]` to `PartialFunction[A, String]`:

```
def foo(pf: PartialFunction[Int, String]): PartialFunction[A, String] = ???
```

For example, `foo(parf)` should return `{case A(0) => "!!!" }`. How would you write function `foo` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To maintain the correct functionality, you need to check if the inner partial function is defined on a parameter you're going to pass:

```
val parf: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case 0 => "!!!" }

case class A(x: Int)

def foo(pf: PartialFunction[Int, String]): PartialFunction[A, String] = {
  case A(i) if pf.isDefinedAt(i) => pf(i)
}
```

If you plan to do it on a larger scale, you might want to convert a partial function to an extractor object, so it can be used in pattern matches directly with a better syntax:

```
trait Extractor[A, B] {
  def unapply(a: A): Option[B]
}

object Extractor {
  implicit def partialFunctionAsExtractor[A, B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): Extractor[A, B] =
    new Extractor[A, B] {
      def unapply(a: A) = if (pf.isDefinedAt(a)) Some(pf(a)) else None
    }
}

def foo2(pf: Extractor[Int, String]): PartialFunction[A, String] = {
    case A(pf(str)) => str
}

foo2(parf) // implicit conversion magic
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't see what got you confused about it? You just need to match-extract the `Int` out of `A` and then let the PF behave as it wants to behave.

```
scala> case class A(x: Int)
// defined class A

scala> val parf: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case 0 => "!!!" }
// parf: PartialFunction[Int,String] = <function1>

scala> def foo(pf: PartialFunction[Int, String]): PartialFunction[A, String] = { 
     |   case A(x) if pf.isDefinedAt(x) => pf(x)
     | }   
// foo: (pf: PartialFunction[Int,String])PartialFunction[A,String]

scala> val parfA = foo(parf)
// parfA: PartialFunction[A,String] = <function1>

scala> parfA(A(0))
//res0: String = !!!

scala> parfA(A(1))
// scala.MatchError: A(1) (of class A)
//   at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:254)
//   at scala.PartialFunction$$anon$1.apply(PartialFunction.scala:252)
//   at $anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:11)
//   at $anonfun$1.applyOrElse(<console>:11)
//   at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:34)
//   at $anonfun$foo$1.applyOrElse(<console>:13)
//   at $anonfun$foo$1.applyOrElse(<console>:13)
//   at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:34)
//   ... 28 elided
```

Comment: This will break behavior of `isDefinedAt` and `lift` on a new function

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov Yes. Great point. That is why - `I don't see what got you confused about it?`

Answer (score 1):

@Oleg Pyzhcov already provided a great solution.  Another approach would be to create a PartialFunction[A, Int] that is defined at A(0), and use `andThen` to chain it with `parf`:

```
val parf: PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case 0 => "!!!" }

case class A(n: Int)

val bar: PartialFunction[A, Int] = { case a: A if a.n == 0 => a.n }

def foo(pf: PartialFunction[Int, String]): PartialFunction[A, String] =
  bar andThen pf
// foo: (pf: PartialFunction[Int,String])PartialFunction[A,String]

foo(parf)
// res1: PartialFunction[A,String] = <function1>
```